# Выбрать список значений по списку связанных значений

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть таблица с полями: **id**, **value**

В таблице:

- для одного **id** могут содержаться несколько разных **value**
- для разных **id** могут быть одинаковые **value**

Пример таблицы:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 |

*Задача*: на вход поступает список значений, составить запрос, который вернет список **id**, **value** которых строго входят в заданный список значений.

*Пояснение*: например в запросе приходит список значений [2,5] - значит запрос должен вернуть только 1й **id**, т.к. для него есть соответствующие **value**. Для 2го **id** есть **value** 2, но нет 5. Для 3го есть **value** 5, но нет 2.

Строго говоря список входящих значений должен являться подмножеством списка **value** для одного **id**, чтобы этот **id** вошел в выборку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE value IN ( {список значений} )
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT value ) = {количество уникальных значений в списке}
```